# Shopify Product page regex match in Google Analytics Goal Funnel

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, goal-tracking

The first step of my goal funnel is not being recognized in analytics
You can clearly see that most of the entrance pages into the "Add to Cart" step come from a url like /products/*
[image: Goal Funnel]

I have set my funnel up like so:

[image: Analytics Funnel]

Is there something wrong with the step 1 regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is your goal **Destination** is not set to `Regular expression`.

If you want to use regex in your steps, you have to specify `Regular expression` in **Destination**

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#funnels
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1116091?hl=en#matchTypes